# Ember js get transitioned to model id in willTransition

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This is my router

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('courses');
    this.resource('course', { path: '/courses/:course_id'}, function(){
    });

});
```

In my CoursesRoute I have -

```
actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
        // how to access the intended transition or the intended model id
        if(this.get('model.id') == 102) { // here model is not accessible
            transition.abort();
        }

        // Since courses is a ArrayController I get all the courses inside this.get('controller.content')

        // But how do I get the model ID of the selected course.
    }
}
```

This is used in the courses template

```
{{#link-to 'course' this class='thumbnail course'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find the ID of the context model like this:

```
actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
        var contexts = transition.intent.contexts; // array of all context models
        var contextID = contexts[0].id; // if you only expect one model, this is its ID
        if(contextID == 102) { // now you can use the ID for your condition
            transition.abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you my friend are an awesome emberano ;)